# What does “snooze factor eleven" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the opening of “An open letter to the White Walker Army” in The New Yorker (June 12), Sarah Larson exclaims:

> Dear White Walkers and Your Thousands of Undead Wights: I get it—you’re scary and disgusting. To Jon Snow and his ragtag, reluctant band of allies, you’re a formidable enemy, an unstoppable harbinger of death; to TV critics, you’re a horrifying thrill. Your triumphant appearance in the “Game of Thrones” episode “Hardhome,” after seasons of teasing, was a coup, a set piece, a breathtaking, daze-inducing experience so pleasurable that it transcended what was already transcendent. To me, however, **you’re a snooze factor eleven.**
>
> http://www.newyorker.com/culture/sarah-larson/an-open-letter-to-the-white-walker-army

Though I assume “snooze factor” is a snooze button, I cannot find the meaning of “snooze factor” in Google search headings.

What does “a snooze factor eleven” mean? Why should it be “Eleven”, not twelve, ten, nine, or even one?

Comment: It's a Star Trek reference. Warp factor 10 and above were the super-dooper (and sometimes impossible) speeds. So "snooze factor 11" uses that phrase ironically to say that something is really boring.

Comment: And a "snooze factor" is a factor which causes you to snooze.

Comment: @JasonM Ah, I assumed it was a reference to "turning it up to eleven," a euphemism for exceeding the maximum volume used by musicians who don't measure in dB (and joked about by Xkcd).

Comment: @user867 Same church, different pew: either way, it's a dial with levels marked one to ten.

Comment: Doesn't anybody know "Spinal Tap"?

Comment: A "snooze" is something that's so boring and predictable that it puts you to sleep.

Comment: @StoneyB. i.e. snooze causer. Is 'snooze factor'  a common English word? Why is  "eleven" necessary?

Comment: "Factor 11" is a play on Star Trek's "warp factor 10" (and the various other idioms developed off of that).

Comment: @user867 and famously joked about in a film that came out a few months before the author of that strip was born.

Comment: As Jason M says, *X factor #* echoes Star Trek, and n=11 expresses a number that's 'off the dial' -- beyond the highest number available.

Comment: @HotLicks: Scales of "from one to ten" were commonplace long before television. ST did the chipping. And  "eleven" means "overloaded the meter".

Comment: @JohnLawler - Star Trek provided the "factor".  (And most folks don't really know what "overload the meter" means.)

Comment: Like, the folks mentioning "Star Trek" - are you just kidding around?

Comment: Warp factor... wtf? No... are @Oldbag and I the *only* ones around who have seen *Spinal Tap*? For Pete's sake: [Spinal Tap "But These Go to 11"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9F5fhJQo34)

Comment: This is clearly a reference to star trek. The "factor" is the key word. Were it intended to be a reference to Spinal Tap there would be a "goes to", not a "factor".

Comment: @zxq9 - I agree with the others, "snooze factor" is a reference to _Star Trek's_ "warp factor". That said, as for the O.P.'s other question – Why should it be “Eleven”, not twelve, ten, or nine? – the _Spinal Tap_ reference explains that quite well.

Comment: It's just ......... funny ..... that anyone thinks this is a reference to Star Trek.

Comment: the writer writing is a **TV and media critic**.  **Of course** she's saying snooze-factor, unlike x-factor.

Comment: Hi Eric ... that is just ... i don't know what to say.  You might as well say **there's no mention of "engage!" or "make it so!" therefore it has no connection at all to "Star Trek"**.    Let's rethink this.  the three words "snooze factor eleven" are making people think of Star Trek.  It's really hard to know how to even address this, it is so ......... disturbing.  the other two words of this trio have **NOTHING -- NO CONNECTION OR EVEN CLOSENESS** to Star Trek.  You guys are feeling that ANYWHERE "factor" is mentioned ... that's a Star Trek reference.

Comment: Hold it!  I've just realised that -- of course -- the massive hit show, the major TV cultural referrent worldwide for 10 years ... X-Factor ................. is of course ......... wait for it .......... **THAT IS A REFERENCE TO STAR TREK!**  Right?  hahaha

Comment: I just up-voted the question... Apparently, this issue needs clarification.

Comment: I continue to find this staggering.  The ONLY CONNECTION to "Star Trek" is the bare word "factor".  It's just ................................... absolutely, totally, unbelievable.  Anyway.  I'm just trying not to comment any more on my wide-eyed amazement at this.  No wonder the show was so popular.  Wait, maybe the "eleven" is a reference to seven of nine?  After all .. it contains numbers.

Comment: It's just occurred to me that there perhaps, literally, people who think the titling of the show "The X Factor" *was a reference to 'warp factor'*.  Hell, maybe they're right.  Maybe that's exactly how it's seen by a certain age group. I don't know anymore.

Comment: _Spacewarp_ and _warp factor_ have been in the science fiction lexicon since the 1930s. "Factor" just means you're using a log scale. Science fiction readers would have known this, even in the  30s. Who can say what ST viewers know? Certainly very few novelties were introduced in ST that weren't standard SF devices -- except for one, now I think on it: only in ST was the use of safety belts and webs in the control room during rough maneuvering dispensed with.

Comment: @JohnLawler indeed, Google books shows many instances of "comfort factor" and others from the 1910s, in real science literature, not science fiction.

Comment: The idea of factor 11 predates spinal tap, they simply made a joke about it. It is the olde timey version of 110%.

Comment: Hmmm.  What's onomatopoeia for snoozing?  Repeat 12 times.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Snooze* is to sleep. By extension it implies extreme boredom.

*Factor* is a measure of something, and is often used along with numbers as in "sun protection factor" as a measure of sunscreen effectiveness, "warp factor" in Star Trek, numbered blood factors.

So "Snooze Factor [something]" would make it understandable as meaning it was very boring and if that "[something]" was a number it would fit a pattern recognised from elsewhere, even though that pattern works differently in different cases.

But what number to use?

Well, in the 1984 comedy "This is Spinal Tap" one character boasted about his custom-made amplifiers:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xgx4k83zzc

> **Nigel Tufnel**: The numbers all go to eleven. Look, right across the board, eleven, eleven, eleven and...
>
> **Marty DiBergi**: Oh, I see. And most amps go up to ten?
>
> **Nigel Tufnel**: Exactly.
>
> **Marty DiBergi**: Does that mean it's louder? Is it any louder?
>
> **Nigel Tufnel**: Well, it's one louder, isn't it? It's not ten. You see, most blokes, you know, will be playing at ten. You're on ten here, all the way up, all the way up, all the way up, you're on ten on your guitar. Where can you go from there? Where?
>
> **Marty DiBergi**: I don't know.
>
> **Nigel Tufnel**: Nowhere. Exactly. What we do is, if we need that extra push over the cliff, you know what we do?
>
> **Marty DiBergi**: Put it up to eleven.
>
> **Nigel Tufnel**: Eleven. Exactly. One louder.
>
> **Marty DiBergi**: Why don't you just make ten louder and make ten be the top number and make that a little louder?
>
> **Nigel Tufnel**: [pause] These go to eleven.

This film was only moderately successful when it came out, but gathered quite a cult following subsequently, and so for people from Anglo-phonic countries of a certain age there is a running joke that the highest possible number for anything is 11.

So to be "snooze factor eleven" isn't just to be boring, but to pull out all the stops and really go all out at being as boring as possible.

Comment: This answer is: wrong!

Comment: @JoeBlow well, you make a strong and compelling case.

Comment: :)  Was typing.  it's half-wrong TBC.

Comment: The first part of this answer is precisely, as if: Imagine an alien had landed and asked **"Why do I hear 'The Beatles' referred to so much?"** and you had very carefully explained that it's a reference to musical beats --- other than mentioning, perhaps in passing, that it was "the world's top pop band of a century."  Good grief.

Comment: @JoeBlow Only if people had been talking about "The Beatles" for half a century before there was a band called that. And the alien had actually asked about Buddy Holly and The Crickets.

Comment: - Although, since electronic devices no longer have antediluvian features like DIALS, I wonder if the humor of this excerpt is lost to the younger generation. When I tell young people that the only reason my parents had me was so someone could change the channel, they look at me like I'm off my meds.

Comment: @Oldbag dials and sliders are still used both physically and as a metaphor in the UI of digital devices, at least for such things as volume. A radio station here had an advert with the slogan "move the dial" as a phrase meaning "switch to listening to us now that we have headhunted some of the most popular radio presenters" and it strike many as anachronistic.

Comment: I have only heard of the group "Spinal Tap", I thought it was a proper heavy metal group, and never knew what the fuss was about. Then in 1985 I got married to an Italian and anything British was banned in our household (long story...). So, I'm very grateful you took the time to explain what was special about "11". P.S I upvoted your answer asa you posted it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Spinal Tap (or perhaps rather, Spın̈al Tap, with a "heavy-metal umlaut") have gone on to play some tours and festivals, so they're sort-of "proper" to that extent.

Comment: They even appeared on The Simpsons - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Otto_Show - that episode manged a Nielsen rating of 11.5 ...

Comment: +1, good job explaining how 'factor' can be a reference to Star Trek while 11 is a separate reference to Spinal Tap

Answer (score 3):

> Is 'snooze factor' a common English word?

Remember in the era of Star Wars, it was very common to riff on "Start Wars"? So, headline writers and article writers would have "Xyz Wars" to the point of overuse.

Today in all English-speaking regions [*"The X-Factor"*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sp5Ws-u8EU) is a huge TV show franchize.  It is common to riff on the name .. so, sleeze factor, etc. Here "snooze factor".

It is especially common in writing about media (as here), writing about other TV shows (as here), and writing originating from media critics (as here).

> "Why should it be “Eleven” ..."

"Eleven", "turn to eleven", "it goes to eleven" etc - from [*This is Spinal Tap*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xgx4k83zzc) - is, along with let's say "Don't Panic" (from *Hitchhiker's Guide*) or "We're not worthy!" (from *Wayne's World*) one of the most famous comic references in English in recent times.  100% of native speakers are familiar with the joke.

Comment: Hi Shannon.  the final sentence was extremely slightly ambiguous: like almost all sentences in English it could be read more than one way.  Since you kindly bothered to leave a comment about it, I quickly edited it slightly. "Where did the dog bite you" (i.e. "on the ass" or "on Main street") is a famous exemplar of such ambiguity in English, so I typed that as a kind of head-nod to your comment. thanks again